# Javascript: array.length The interface is unknown

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I have a window which contains HTML , CSS and a script block containing the following script. (abridged version)

```
var arrPages = new Array();

function ShowPage(p){
   for(var i=0; i<arrPages.length; i++){
      if(p == arrPages[i]){
         //@Shows page
      }
   }
}
```

Additional HTML is dynamically written into the popup after it has been opened based on data in the parent window, The content of arrPages is passed from parent window to child in the form of popupWin.arrPages = arrayData; the parent window is then closed automatically. (i cant just recycle the existing window only re-configuring it's content)

Part of the dynamically generated/written html are several div's with onclick events:

```
<div class='page' onclick='ShowPage(0);'>1</div>
<div class='page' onclick='ShowPage(1);'>2</div>
<div class='page' onclick='ShowPage(1);'>3</div>
...etc
```

The javascript here works perfectly when running the popup with it's parent window still open, but the second one closes the parent window (automatically or manually) the ShowPage(p) function throws the error "The interface is unknown"

Debugging is pointing to the error occuring on arrPages.length, even though arrPages is a bonafied array containing valid data.

Thank you for any assistance as i have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: I'm guessing you may need to do a deep copy of the array. JS is object-oriented after all, so if you just assign it from window A to window B, both windows are referencing the exact same array. But when you close window A, which "owns" the array, the array may get "destroyed" even though B is using it. Just guessing, but seems reasonable.

Comment: What you say makes sense, and describes the behaviour im seeing. I wasn't really wanting to write the array out to a string and then string.split() is but i guess that's the safest method of deep copying the data

Comment: Well, if you want to use strings, I'd suggest `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` instead of a DIY solution. Otherwise, you can find plenty of ready-made functions to make deep copies; it shouldn't be necessary to use strings or JSON. Just have a function like `setPages()` on the popup window, and call it from the parent window. Have the function do the work of making a "local" copy of the array you pass to it. Either way, try the most simple solution first to make sure that the theory is sound, before you write a lot more code

Comment: I ended up having the child page reprocess the content of the array, only took 2-3 lines of code. There are some perks about 100% control of the data being fed to the system, Most of what i do nowadays is designed to be used on specific software and hardware configs using relatively canned data,